# What's the best way to inverse sort in scala?

Tags: scala

What is the best way to do an inverse sort in scala?  I imagine the following is somewhat slow.

```
list.sortBy(_.size).reverse
```

Is there a conveinient way of using sortBy but getting a reverse sort?  I would rather not need to use `sortWith`.

Comment: the solutions below are all very nice but I still find your original way of doing this simpler to read. 

I have verified that there is a computational drawback to this way of writing as you suspected. The test I did is like this:

    val clock = new Timer
    (1 to 1e6.toInt).sorted(Ordering[Int].reverse)
    clock.addLap("correct way")
    (1 to 1e6.toInt).sorted.reverse
    clock.addLap("incorrect way")
    println(clock.toString)

    [correct way, lap = 76, dur. = 76] | [incorrect way, lap = 326, dur. = 250]

Comment: What's the drawback of using `sortWith`? Is it more expensive?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

There may be the obvious way of changing the sign, if you sort by some numeric value

```
list.sortBy(- _.size)
```

More generally, sorting may be done by method sorted with an implicit `Ordering`, which you may make explicit, and `Ordering` has a `reverse` (not the list `reverse` below)
You can do

```
list.sorted(theOrdering.reverse)
```

If the ordering you want to reverse is the implicit ordering, you can get it by `implicitly[Ordering[A]]` (`A` the type you're ordering on) or better `Ordering[A]`. That would be

```
list.sorted(Ordering[TheType].reverse)
```

`sortBy` is like using `Ordering.by`, so you can do

```
list.sorted(Ordering.by(_.size).reverse)
```

Maybe not the shortest to write (compared to minus) but intent is clear

**Update**

The last line does not work. To accept the `_` in `Ordering.by(_.size)`, the compiler needs to know on which type we are ordering, so that it may type the `_`. It may seems that would be the type of the element of the list, but this is not so, as the signature of sorted is
`def sorted[B >: A](ordering: Ordering[B])`. The ordering may be on `A`, but also on any ancestor of `A` (you might use `byHashCode : Ordering[Any] = Ordering.by(_.hashCode)`). And indeed, the fact that list is covariant forces this signature.
One can do

```
list.sorted(Ordering.by((_: TheType).size).reverse)
```

but this is much less pleasant.

Comment: Super helpful--I wasn't sure if I were asking a dumb question, but I learned a lot from your answer!

Comment: Except that it does not work. I should never answer when I have no REPL handy. See update.

Comment: And to sort on a secondary field, return a tuple: `list.sortBy(x => (-x.size, x.forTiesUseThisField))`

Comment: Instead of `list.sorted(Ordering.by((_: TheType).size).reverse)` consider `list.sorted(Ordering.by[TheType, Int](_.size).reverse)` it clearer (but longer) for my point of veiw.

Comment: I personally like `list.sortBy(_.size)(Ordering[Int].reverse)` also.

Comment: The first one `list.sortBy(- _.size)` is incorrect, because ``-Int.MinValue == Int.MinValue``.

Answer (score 130):

```
list.sortBy(_.size)(Ordering[Int].reverse)
```

Comment: I feel like this should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 28):

maybe to shorten it a little more:

```
def Desc[T : Ordering] = implicitly[Ordering[T]].reverse

List("1","22","4444","333").sortBy( _.size )(Desc)
```

Answer (score 19):

Easy peasy (at least in case of `size`):

```
scala> val list = List("abc","a","abcde")
list: List[java.lang.String] = List(abc, a, abcde)

scala> list.sortBy(-_.size)
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(abcde, abc, a)

scala> list.sortBy(_.size)
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(a, abc, abcde)
```

Answer (score 14):

Both `sortWith` and `sortBy` have a compact syntax:

```
case class Foo(time:Long, str:String)

val l = List(Foo(1, "hi"), Foo(2, "a"), Foo(3, "X"))

l.sortWith(_.time > _.time)  // List(Foo(3,X), Foo(2,a), Foo(1,hi))

l.sortBy(- _.time)           // List(Foo(3,X), Foo(2,a), Foo(1,hi))

l.sortBy(_.time)             // List(Foo(1,hi), Foo(2,a), Foo(3,X))
```

I find the one with `sortWith` easier to understand.

Comment: Says no implicits found for Order(any) scala 2.13

Answer (score 11):

```
val list = List(2, 5, 3, 1)
list.sortWith(_>_) -> res14: List[Int] = List(5, 3, 2, 1)
list.sortWith(_<_) -> res14: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 10):

`sortBy` has implicit parameter `ord` which provides ordering

```
def sortBy [B] (f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): List[A]
```

so, we can define own `Ordering` object

```
scala> implicit object Comp extends Ordering[Int] {
 | override def compare (x: Int, y: Int): Int = y - x
 | }
defined module Comp

List(3,2,5,1,6).sortBy(x => x)
res5: List[Int] = List(6, 5, 3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a generic method you can use this in Scala 3;

```
extension [T, A: Ordering](a: List[T])
  def sortByDesc(f: T => A) = a.sortBy(f)(Ordering[A].reverse)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility in cases where you pass a function that you may not be able to modify directly to an Arraybuffer via sortWith for example:

```
val buf = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()
buf += 3
buf += 9
buf += 1

// the sort function (may be passed through from elsewhere)
def sortFn = (A:Int, B:Int) => { A < B }

// the two ways to sort below
buf.sortWith(sortFn)                        // 1, 3, 9
buf.sortWith((A,B) => { ! sortFn(A,B) })    // 9, 3, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code ;)

```
val wordCounts = logData.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                        .map(word => (word, 1))
                        .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)

wordCounts.sortBy(- _._2).collect()
```

Comment: This is not incorrect, but the interesting part (the second line) is drowned out by the unneeded line before it. Basically, the point here is that one way to do a reverse sort is to to negate the sort value.

Answer (score 0):

```
val listOfIntegers = List(5, 1, 2, 4, 3)

listOfIntegers.sortBy(i=>i).reverse
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?