# Sort Array of Int

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark

I am trying to `sort` the following `array` in `descending` order but can't figure out how.

I have tried using `.sort` and `.sortWith` but they don't appear to be applicable to `arrays`?

```
val result = postIdCount.withFilter(_._2 > 5).map(_._1.toInt)

result.collect

Array[Int] = Array(41, 974, 662, 9554, 116, 4942, 410, 2269, 5443, 5357, 9435, 2293, 266, 711, 441, 61, 3738, 22, 6318, 8390, 497, 19, 9364, 412, 893, 334, 9000, 678, 313, 253, 979, 842, 4914, 2651, 6547, 6576, 1159, 5224, 1107, 52, 810, 361, 694, 739, 904, 5706, 422, 778, 9818, 758, 130, 265, 6107, 155, 2618, 8941, 8963, 834, 326, 731, 2368, 430, 1253)
```

Would anyone know how I might achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:** This is what I have so far:

When I try and add:

```
val result = postIdCount.withFilter(_._2 > 5).map(_._1.toInt).sorted(Ordering[Integer].reverse)
```

I get an error saying:

```
error: value sorted is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to inverse sort in scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802851/whats-the-best-way-to-inverse-sort-in-scala)

Comment: You need to sort out your code. You ask about sorting an array, but the error message clearly isn't about an array, but about some obscure type which isn't part of Scala. You need to figure out first where this strange type comes from, and why you have this strange type instead of an array.

Comment: @JörgWMittag When I do `result.collect`, it seems to be an array?

Comment: Maybe. But whatever object you are calling `sorted` on isn't an array. Again, the error message very clearly says that it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val sorted = postIdCount
   .withFilter(_._2 > 5)
   .map(_._1.toInt)
   .sortBy(identity, ascending = false)
```

This returns a sorted `RDD[Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

`postIdCount.withFilter(_._2 > 5).map(_._1.toInt)` gives you `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` not `Array`.

Try

```
postIdCount.withFilter(_._2 > 5).map(_._1.toInt).collect.sorted(Ordering[Int].reverse)`
```

`collect` function returns all the elements of the dataset as an array. But this collects all data to a single machine in spark cluster.

Comment: I tried this and got the following: `error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.math.Ordering[Integer]
 required: scala.math.Ordering[Any]
Note: Integer <: Any, but trait Ordering is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`.`

Comment: @Archer Use `Ordering[Int]`

Answer (score 0):

```
val sortedArray = array.sorted
```

Comment: That's ascending, not descending.

Answer (score 0):

```
val sorted = array.sorted(Ordering[Int].reverse)
```

Comment: Hi Dimitry, I tried this but got an error stating `error: value sorted is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]`. I have provided more details in my question.

Comment: Looks like the structure you're using is not an array, rather `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD`. So this one should be applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838614/how-to-sort-an-rdd-in-scala-spark