# Scala: reverse order of Sorting.quickSort?

Tags: scala, sorting

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7803042/5863503) explains how to reverse the order of sorting an array while using its built-in method `.sortBy`. How do I reverse the order of the sorting when using `scala.util.Sorting.quickSort`?

Comment: Why not in the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
import scala.util.Sorting.quickSort

val a = Array(1, 2, 3)
quickSort[Int](a)(Ordering[Int].reverse)
//       ^---^ the most important bit
println(a.toVector) // Vector(3, 2, 1)
```

`quickSort` is a function that has overloads for `Int`, `Float` and `Double`, which don't let you specify ordering, and the generic one for any type `[T]` that has `Ordering` instance.

If you have an array of `Int`, `Float` or `Double`, overload resolution will prefer specialized versions, so you will not be able to pass `Ordering` manually unless you specify a type parameter (so compiler now only has one choice).

For arrays of things other than these three types (e.g. `Long`s), you can omit the type parameter, because there's only one valid option:

```
val b = Array(1L, 2L, 3L)
quickSort(b)(Ordering[Long].reverse)
println(b.toVector) // Vector(3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the type signature of `quickSort` you should find:

```
def quickSort[K](a: Array[K])(implicit arg0: math.Ordering[K]): Unit
```

Obviously this means that you can customize the behaviour by implementing an implicit `Ordering[K]` (or passing in one).

Example:

```
val a = Array(3, 4, 2, 3)
quickSort[Int](a)(Ordering.Int.reverse)
```

Comment: You should only use in-place sorts for performance reasons; modifying/updating values in-place makes reasoning about your code extremely hard.