# How to pass ordering to scala.util.Sorting.quickSort

Tags: scala

I'm trying to pass reverse ordering to the `scala.util.Sorting.quickSort` with this code:

```
val a = Array(3, 5, 1, 2)
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(a)(Ordering.Int.reverse)
```

It doesn't work saying that:

> Error: Unit does not take parameters

However, the code like that works:

```
val a = Array(3, 5, 1, 2)
a.sorted(Ordering.Int.reverse)
```

I don't understand why the `quickSort` example doesn't work? The `Ordering.Int.reverse` produce `Ordering[Int]` and according to documentation, the `quickSort` accepts it implicitly.

I'm running with Scala 2.12.7.

Comment: It's picking up the wrong overload

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48702923/2928853

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on  Yuval Itzchakov's comment, here is the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/e954b423fdc379f4f38f792fc589586e493dd66b/src/library/scala/util/Sorting.scala#L47) for `scala.util.Sorting.quickSort`:

```
def quickSort(a: Array[Int]): Unit = java.util.Arrays.sort(a)
```

A few lines down, [another](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/e954b423fdc379f4f38f792fc589586e493dd66b/src/library/scala/util/Sorting.scala#L58) overloaded quicksort is defined as:

```
def quickSort[K: Ordering](a: Array[K]): Unit = {...
```

You mean to use this latter one. But when you call quickSort, the compiler is picking the first one which does not accept an `Ordering` in its parameter list so it complains about extra parameters. You will need to specify type parameter if you are using `Int`, `Double`, or `Float` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48702923/2928853). To summarize:

```
val a : Array[Int] = Array(3, 5, 1, 2)
val b = Array(3L, 5L, 1L, 2L)  //Longs do not have this problem!
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort[Int](a)(Ordering.Int.reverse)
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(b)(Ordering.Long.reverse)
println(a.toList)
println(b.toList)

List(5, 3, 2, 1)
List(5, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it's make sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation the signature of method that uses Ordering is:

```
def quickSort[K](a: Array[K])(implicit arg0: math.Ordering[K]): Unit
```

> Sort array a with quicksort, using the Ordering on its elements. This
>   algorithm sorts in place, so no additional memory is used aside from
>   what might be required to box individual elements during comparison.

try this:

```
scala> val a = Array(3, 5, 1, 2)
a: Array[Int] = Array(3, 5, 1, 2)

scala> scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(a)(Ordering.Int.reverse)
<console>:13: error: Unit does not take parameters
       scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(a)(Ordering.Int.reverse)
                                      ^

scala> scala.util.Sorting.quickSort[Int](a)(Ordering[Int].reverse)

scala> a
res2: Array[Int] = Array(5, 3, 2, 1)
```